# PHP: Get filename (without extension) of uploaded file without knowing its path?

Tags: php

`$_FILES['userfile']['name']` will return the extension. Is there a way to get just the name (no extension) besides using `pathinfo()['filename']`?

For context, I want to create a directory with `mkdir` based on a filename. Say you upload a zip file called `bobby`, I want to make a directory called bobby, not bobby.zip.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: So basically, basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']) ? If so, thanks.

Comment: You could use basename as suggested in the comments or you could use explode once you get the complete name.

Comment: @MarcB you are a little bit offensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
echo basename(__FILE__, '.php');
```

**edit**
My excuse, did not read it good.

```
pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME)
```

should to the trick!

Comment: Yes, this is working. Can't believe I overlooked this when reading through the documentation.